# Issue installing python requirements. ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

Tags: python

I am trying to fork a web app project that I have downloaded.

I have a requirements.txt file that looks like this.

```
asgiref==3.2.3
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
Django==3.0.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.8
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2019.3
requests==2.22.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
urllib3==1.25.7
cryptography==2.8
oauth2client==4.1.3
google-cloud-storage==1.25.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.10.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.23.1
openpyxl==3.0.3
freezegun==0.3.14
pandas==1.0.0
xlrd==1.2.0
xlsxwriter==0.9.8
six==1.13.0
grpcio==1.29.0
```

Here is my folder structure.

[image]

When I am in terminal, inside the app directory. I am running

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

and getting the following very long output error!

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1

[image]

Comment: Did you forget to include the "very long" error?

Comment: The command would be `pip3` rather than `pip 3`

Comment: @mkrieger1 Apologies I have added the error screenshot.

Comment: @dschurman Apologies the command i have been running is pip3, it was just an error when I made this post.